# php button session check and allow access

Tags: php

this is not help to me 
[PHP check session, checking multiple variables to allow access to specific pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28224253/php-check-session-checking-multiple-variables-to-allow-access-to-specific-pages)

[php condition on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484951/php-condition-on-button)

[PHP if condition number issue [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798304/php-if-condition-number-issue)

[PHP if condition strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954690/php-if-condition-strange)

i try simple php CRUD with session 
user.php if login usercan only access ore its print error but 
this is user.php top lines

```
<?php include('server.php') ?>
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
// header("Location:login.php");
echo "nee to login to access this page" ;

exit;
session_destroy();
}
?>
```

and this my delete button code

```
<a href="server.php?delete=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class ="btn btn-danger" > delete </a>
```

when this button gt clicked ip/user.php?delete=id   (id get from data base)  when with out login when  type this `ip/user.php?delete=20` its delete from data base how can i stop that?

its my server.php for delete

```
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $id = $_GET['delete'];
    $qry = "DELETE FROM crud WHERE id=$id" ;
    mysqli_query($conn, $qry);

    $_SESSION['message'] = "recoard deleted success";
$_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";
header('location: user.php');
}
```

Comment: So its like without login if you try to hit the URL then it gets deleted right?

Comment: no i just type url ip.user.php?delete=20   its day error but its delete from data bases

Comment: Sorry didnt get you?

Comment: if user not login theycat access user.php but itf the directy type user.php?delete=10 its delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//on the top of page check session is set or not
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
   if (isset($_GET['delete'])) 
  {
    $id = $_GET['delete'];
    $qry = "DELETE FROM crud WHERE id=$id" ;
    mysqli_query($conn, $qry);

    $_SESSION['message'] = "recoard deleted success";
    $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";
    header('location: user.php');
  }
}
else
{
  echo 'cant access this page you need to login first';
}
```

if you still face issue try to print $_SESSION array and check does sesison really gets destroy?

If not then on logout.php

```
unset($_SESSION['name']);
session_destroy();
```

Comment: So on that page try to print_r($_SESSION) and check if yoy really get those values? If not then you might have issue for logout as session is not destroying...